# Do I need to set up a PKI to secure D2C and C2D (IOT) communication in Azure?

Tags: azure, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, azure-iot-hub, pki

Im wondering if I need to set up a Public Key Infrastructure in order to ensure a secure Device to Cloud and Cloud to Device connection?
I  have several IoT devices which should communicate over MQTT.
To ensure that the device X is actually device X that is sending the data to IoT Hub in Azure, do i need to set up a Managed PKI?
I've read several microsoft documentations but I did not understand.
Do I only have to upload the device certificate in Azure IoT Hub and afterwards when writing the device client give the device certificate as parameter?
How can I achieve a secure communication between the device and Azure and also make sure that the device is the device it is pretending to be?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to secure device connections to IoT Hub. In both cases, you need to register your device in the IoT Hub device registry before it can connect:

- SAS tokens. You can obtain a SAS token for a device from the device registry. When the device presents the token, IoT Hub verifies that it was issued by your IoT hub and that the device is registered.
- X.509 certificates. This approach requires you to upload a root or intermediate certificate to your IoT hub. If a device presents a leaf certificate derived from the root or intermediate certificate, then it's allowed to connect.

To learn more, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas.

Additionally, IoT Hub uses TLS to secure all communications. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-tls-support. This typically doesn't require any setup or configuration on your behalf before it's allowed to connect.